# XML Multiple Category and Sub-Category structure

Tags: xml, data-structures, categorization

What is the best data structure for an XML document to represent a N-Category for a subject?  I want give the possibility to the user to create infinite category end sub-category, and then grouping item in these.

I know how to implement this in E/R database ... but in XML?